# Cannot use tcpdump's -Q on Mac

Tags: macos, tcpdump

```sh
DEVs-iMac:dev$ sudo tcpdump -Qout -nnSX -c 1 -w packet.pcap port 9656
Password:
tcpdump: cannot parse term at: 
tcpdump: invalid expression "out"
```

I'm trying to dump all outgoing IP packets. It works on Linux but not on Mac. Does anyone have any idea why?

I figured out its only -Qout that gives me problems I tried to rearrange it but no matter where I place it, it doesn't work.

Comment: There is no option like this on Mac - see [this platform specific man page](https://ss64.com/osx/tcpdump.html) or just call `man tcpdump` on your system.  Also [this general man page](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html) clearly says *"-Q direction ... Not available on all platforms."*

Comment: It looks like it does because it comes up if you type in tcpdump -Q like here tcpdump: option requires an argument -- Q
tcpdump version tcpdump version 4.9.2 -- Apple version 83.200.2
libpcap version 1.8.1 -- Apple version 79.250.1
LibreSSL 2.2.7
Usage: tcpdump [-aAbdDefhHIJKlLnNOpqStuUvxX#] [ -B size ] [ -c count ]
  [ -C file_size ] [ -E algo:secret ] [ -F file ] [ -G seconds ]
  [ -i interface ] [ -j tstamptype ] [ -M secret ] [ --number ]
  [ -Q in|out|inout ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Linux vs Macos tcpdump

You cannot use the `-Q` option on Macos-builtin tcpdump because it has additions from Apple. You can see that they are different software by looking at their version info:

#### Macos version

```sh
macos-10.14$ sudo tcpdump --version
tcpdump version tcpdump version 4.9.2 -- Apple version 83.200.2
libpcap version 1.8.1 -- Apple version 79.250.1
LibreSSL 2.2.7
```

#### Linux version

```sh
ubuntu-18.04$ sudo tcpdump --version
tcpdump version 4.9.2
libpcap version 1.8.1
OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
```

#### Manpages

Confusingly, `man tcpdump` on a Macos terminal shows -Q, which is not available. For comparison:

- Linux's [tcpdump manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tcpdump)
- Macos' [tcpdump manpage](https://ss64.com/osx/tcpdump.html) (courtesy of SS64)

### Alternatives

You could build [from source](https://www.tcpdump.org/#source) if direction is important to you. This [may or may not](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/issues/760) be possible based on your architecture.

Comment: I will try to build it from source and add direction which is really important to me. Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind that you can use a capture filter with mac, ip, port, or other defining characteristics to mimic -Q in or out. Obviously, it's not the same, but may be *faster* to set up for your needs.

Comment: I strictly need only the outgoing packages. Would you happen to know the filter I would need to use? I compiled it from source and "installed" it with make install but it still doesn't let me use -Qout. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're still having issues using a documented feature after installing from source, you should [file a bug](https://www.tcpdump.org/#patches).

Comment: I just compiled tcpdump 4.9.3 (./configure, make and make install) but when I check with --version its still 4.9.2 so it didn't set the path correctly not sure why

Comment: tcpdump.4.9.3: en0: pcap_setdirection() failed: Setting direction to PCAP_D_OUT is not supported on BPF

Comment: I installed libpcap 1.9.1 via brew but when I check the version of tcpdump its stilled linked to the libpcap version 1.8.1 -- Apple version 79.250.1 how can I link 1.9.1 to tcpdump?

Comment: Yeah that also looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to the post below, I responded that this command `tcpdump -Qdir=out` works fine, but something doesn’t look implemented correctly with the `—-direction` Flag in MacOSX.

[Change libpcap Version on macOS (Apple removed a feature)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641670/change-libpcap-version-on-macos-apple-removed-a-feature)