# Change libpcap Version on macOS (Apple removed a feature)

Tags: macos, ubuntu, tcpdump, libpcap

I just want to use tcpdump with the same -Qout functionality that is available on Ubuntu.

On macOS tcpdump and libpcap have been stripped off the functionality to filter with -Qout.

```
tcpdump -Qout -nnSX -c 10 -w packet.pcap port XXXX
tcpdump: cannot parse term at: 
tcpdump: invalid expression "out"
```

I have build tcpdump (./configure, make, make install) and `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH`.
When I check with

```
tcpdump --version
tcpdump version 4.9.3
libpcap version 1.8.1 -- Apple version 79.250.1
```

Now If I try the same dump I get another message:

```
tcpdump --direction=out -nnSX -c 10 -w packet.pcap port XXXX
tcpdump: en0: pcap_setdirection() failed: Setting direction to PCAP_D_OUT is not supported on BPF
```

I have also downloaded the source for libpcap-1.9.0 and tried to build it the same way (./configure, make, make install).

```
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     
invocation)
make: *** [libpcap.dylib] Error 1
```

I need to somehow build and link libpcap-1.9.0 to tcpdump 4.9.3 so when I use tcpdump it will use libpcap 1.9.0.

EDIT:
I have installed libpcap 1.9.1 with brew and exported the path with

```
  echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/libpcap/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

but it still shows me that its linked to the system default 1.8.1

```
tcpdump --version
tcpdump version 4.9.3
libpcap version 1.8.1 -- Apple version 79.250.1
```

Comment: This question is better suited for [apple.stackexchange.com](https://apple.stackexchange.com). To reiterate on previous questions you've asked: It's worth your while to file a bug with tcpdump, especially to get clarification on `PCAP_D_OUT is not supported on BPF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more accurately described as "Apple *never implemented* a feature".

The underlying capture mechanism on macOS is called "BPF", for "Berkeley Packet Filter"; it was originally developed by one of the people at Lawrence Berkeley Laboratories who created libpcap and tcpdump (Van Jacobson).  It's provided by various BSD-flavored OSes, including FreeBSD, NetBSD, OpenBSD, and DragonFly BSD - and macOS.

FreeBSD and NetBSD's BPFs had a feature added to let a program configure it to capture only incoming packets, only outgoing packets, or both incoming and outgoing packets; OpenBSD has a similar feature (with some differences in the details, so I need to go back and add support for that to the tcpdump.org libpcap).

macOS, however, never implemented that feature.  (That's essentially what "PCAP_D_OUT is not supported on BPF", although that error message should probably be changed to something that doesn't use names from the libpcap API, as users might not know what "PCAP_D_OUT" is.)

(Oh, and Apple's tcpdump uses -Q for its own purposes, so they'd have to do some hack to allow it to be used for direction *and* for metadata filtering.  Fortunately, tcpdump also supports --direction=, so Apple could, at least, use that if they ever implement the direction feature in BPF.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that maybe just the flag `--direction` is not working as expected, this command works as expected on mac OSX...

```
tcpdump -Qdir=out -nnSX -c 10 -w packet.pcap port XXXX
```

You can see this info in the manpage for `tcpdump` under **PACKET MEDATDATA FILTER**

> The syntax support the following keywords to denote which of packet
> metadata contents is to be compared:
>
> ```
>           if     interface name
>           proc   process name
>           pid    process ID
>           svc    service class
>           dir    direction
>           eproc  effective process name
>           epid   effective process ID
> ```