# Analogue of "any" pseudo-device in macos

Tags: macos, capture, tcpdump, any

Is there any possibility to capture packets by tcpdump from all devices in MacOS?
In Linux I would use 'sudo tcpdump -i any'. In my MacOS when I execute 'sudo tcpdump -D', I don't see "any" pseudo-device.

Answer (score 3):

*Per @ChristopherMaynard:*
tcpdump docs specify `any` as working on linux: ``` On Linux systems with 2.2 or later kernels, an interface argument of ``any'' can be used to capture packets from all interfaces. ``` However, it is not actually OS-specific.

---

tcpdump accepts the `any` interface on macos in my testing, so in answer to your question, the analog of `any` on linux is `any` on macos:

```sh
bash-5.0 $ sudo tcpdump -i any
tcpdump: data link type PKTAP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type PKTAP (Apple DLT_PKTAP), capture size 262144 bytes
09:43:57.789302 IP6 dsldevice7.attlocal.net.domain > 2600:1700:a700:7340:6dad:2758:c536:f29f.56483: 4283 1/0/0 SOA (85)
09:43:57.789324 IP6 2600:1700:a700:7341:6dad:2759:c536:f29f > dsldevice7.attlocal.net: ICMP6, destination unreachable, unreachable port, 2600:1700:a700:7340:6ded:2759:c536:f29f udp port 56423, length 141
...
```

tcpdump should have the same options ([manpage](https://www.tcpdump.org/manpages/tcpdump.1.html))
 on both macos and linux, apart from those detailed below. If you have an older version of tcpdump (my version is 4.9.3/Apple version 83.200.3), you can update it with `brew install tcpdump`.

### Macos/Linux Tcpdump Differences

You should still look at the manpages when in doubt, but this is a summary of differences:

#### Linux

- `-Q direction` : Choose send/receive direction (in/out/inout)

#### Macos

- `-k` : Control display of packet metadata
- `-Q` : Specify a filter expression based on packet metadata
- `-P` : Save to pcapng

**Note**: Unlike Linux or *BSD, Macos [does not support -Q direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58641670/change-libpcap-version-on-macos-apple-removed-a-feature).

Comment: It would be nice if the tcpdump man page were updated so it was clearer that the "any" interface isn't limited to only Linux systems, <quote>On Linux systems with 2.2 or later kernels, an interface argument of ``any'' can be used to capture packets from all interfaces.</quote>.

Comment: Cheers for the ever helpful comments @ChristopherMaynard. Added to the answer (please feel free to edit answers, as you have more authoritative knowledge on the subject)

Comment: I'm humbled that you think I have more authoritative knowledge on this subject, but the real authority on this subject is Guy Harris.  Unfortunately, I don't think he's on this site anymore.  It's a bit surprising that the tcpdump man page only mentions Linux though, especially since Guy worked at Apple.  Regardless, if the man page is causing confusion for Mac users (not me), it could be updated, but most likely not without a bug report, so if that's something maxim-proshin would like to see changed, an issue should be filed at https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/issues

Comment: Lastly, if the "any" interface is supported on Mac but "tcpdump -D" doesn't list it, then that's arguably another issue that should be raised too.  On Linux, "tcpdump -D" will display that interface as "any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces)", so the expectation would be that it would be similarly displayed on Mac as well.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard That's my point. Of the people who respond on Stack Overflow on the tcpdump tag, you provide the highest quality information.  Whether there exist better authorities is irrelevant if they don't participate.

Comment: This is just my opinion, but if you want consistent behavior from linux utilities, you should use Docker. There are sooo many utilities that are maintained by apple (like tcpdump) that are different from their Linux counterparts. Most GNU coreutils come to mind (sed, grep, readlink, etc. have annoyingly different command flags). And then Macos ships with Python 2.7... At some level, this is a question of whether apple will update their utilities rather than whether the utilities should be fixed upstream.

Comment: In my experience,  tcpdump 4.99.0, installed via brew,  running under OSX 10.15.7 both with and without sudo, does not accept the "-i any" parameter.    I even tried two -i  parameters, and it only notices the last one.